# How to get the current pathname in the app directory of Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using the experimental `app` folder in Next.js 13, where they have replaced `next/router` with `next/navigation`, so I imported the `useRouter` hook accordingly.  I do not see the property `pathname` in the router, which does exist in `next/router`'s router.

> Property 'pathname' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'

My use case is to highlight the link in my navbar that the user is currently on. This is what I tried:

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';


const StyledNavLink: React.FC<NavLinkProps> = ({ to, children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  ...
  return (
    <Link href={to} className={getNavLinkClass({isActive: router.pathname === to})}>
      {children}
    </Link>
  );
};
```

Is there anything I can do to get the current path name or something else to add my classes to the active link?

Comment: you can use [`usePathname`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-pathname) but it doesn't work with server components yet

Answer (score 78, accepted):

When using the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router (directory), the `pathname` has its hook called `usePathname`. Here is a quote from the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname):

> The `usePathname` hook allows you to read the current URL **pathname** from a **Client Component**.

Find below an example, and notice the `'use client'` at the top:

```
'use client';

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

export default function Page() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  return <div>{pathname}</div>;
}
```

As of now, the doc doesn’t mention a way to get the `pathname` server side. However, you could use the technique inspired by this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704#issuecomment-1411186664), combining  Next.js [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware) and request `headers`:

```js
// middleware.js

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set("x-pathname", request.nextUrl.pathname);

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
}
```

```js
// app/page.js

import { headers } from "next/headers";

export default async function Page() {
  const headersList = headers();

  return <div>{headersList.get("x-pathname")}</div>;
}
```

And if you are using [Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) (aka the `[id]` folders), and you want to know the value of the slug, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76113271/15288641).

Answer (score 13):

If you are looking to get the current active pathname on the server side component/page/layout, you can use headers from next/headers.

```
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export function Component() {
  const headersList = headers();
  const activePath = headersList.get("x-invoke-path");
  // const activeUrl = headersList.get("referer");
  // const activeHost = headersList.get("host");
  
  return (<div>{activePath}</div>)
}
```

Comment: Is it next.js setting this header?

Comment: Yes @D0m3 , it is set by next.js.

Comment: I didn't find `x-invoke-path`, but `next-url` works.

Comment: Actually this solution is not recommended by nextjs and does not work on vercel, see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54711#issuecomment-1697436921

Comment: Also, I believe this would de-opt you out of static rendering: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#dynamic-functions

Comment: Correct, from the recent documentation it seems there is no way to get the current URL in the server layout component, the only way is to use middleware but that too is not recommended. :(

Answer (score 1):

One way (albeit a bit hacky) to get the `pathname` on the server side which doesn't require middleware is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75894116/17003575):

> Nextjs13 app dir doesn't have a nice API for this yet. It'll be nice if the props passed down the `segment`.
>
> For now, you can use `children.props.childProp.segment` to get the path of your route on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get easily the current pathname on your client server component :

`page.jsx`

```
export default function Page({ params }) {
  const pathname = params;
  console.log(pathname) // return an Object
}
```

It works like useSearchParams in the documentation
[Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#server-components)

Difficult to find.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how I do it through the server side:

```
export const POST = (request: Request) => {
  const pathname = new URL(request.url).pathname;
  return new Response(`You requested from ${pathname}`, { status: 200 });
};
```