# How to get route pathname inside nextjs 13 app using the latest app directory? "Server Side"

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm using the experimental appDir in Next.js 13, and want to get the URL path of the request. I need this info to set the searchparams before I do the redirection.
I want to get the request path on the server side.

There is a question with similar to this. [How to get current pathname in app directory with Next 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74584091/how-to-get-current-pathname-in-app-directory-with-next-13)
However it concerns with getting pathname on the client side.

I have tried looking into the Layout option and it has props of only children and params. I will not be able to reconstruct the URL with that info. I would like to know where the request is coming from on the server side. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The linked [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74584091/how-to-get-the-current-pathname-in-the-app-directory-of-next-js-13) has been updated to answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

Nextjs13 app dir doesn't have a nice API for this yet. It'll be nice if the props passed down the `segment`.

For now, you can use `children.props.childProp.segment` to get the path of your route on the server.

Comment: Could you share that how you discovered this one?

Comment: @emre just experimentation

Answer (score 4):

You probably might want to use `searchParams`

```
export default function Page({ params, searchParams }) {
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Should have more upvotes

Answer (score 2):

You can pass params to the function and can access to the dynamic route in this case i assume your dynamic route is [id]

```
export default function Page({params}) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>Page for {params.id}</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: How do you pass the params?

Comment: They are just there , you'll see them when you log

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware file to achieve this.

```js
    // middleware.ts
    import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
    
    export function middleware(request: Request) {
    
      // get the URL from request header
      const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
      requestHeaders.set('x-url', request.url);
    
      // pass the header to the layout
      return NextResponse.next({
        request: {
          headers: requestHeaders,
        }
      });
    }
```

To get it in layout:

```js
    // app/layout.tsx
    import { headers } from 'next/headers';
    
    export default function RootLayout() {
      const headersList = headers();
      // read the custom x-url header
      const header_url = headersList.get('x-url') || "";
    }
```

> **Warning:** Doing this will turn off the Server-Side Generation and will trigger Server-Side Rendering because functions like cookies(), headers() are dynamic. They can also result in Cache Miss!

Reference: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704#issuecomment-1411186664

You can read the complete issue here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704