# Read URL dynamic parameter/slug with Next.js in the app folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a problem getting the parameter inside Dynamic Routing. I keep getting errors when reading:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'themenID' of 'router.query' as it is undefined.

In addition, I cannot use `next/router` but have to integrate the router from `next/navigation`. But this one does not have the query property. I use Next.js version 13

The path is called like this: `http://localhost:3000/MainThema/2`.

app/MainThema/[themenID]/page.js:

```js
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React from "react";

export default function MainThema() {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router);

  const { themenID } = router.query;

  return <div>MainThema </div>;
}
```

Comment: Why is next/router not working?

Comment: I get that: 'You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead'

Comment: Yeah, in the app folder, it should be `next/navigation`. But that's not your main issue. Check my below answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can read on the [doc](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#dynamic-segments), your [`page.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page) component gets passed a `params` object when it's in a dynamic segment. And this `params` would contain your dynamic route id, like so:

```
// app/MainThema/[themenID]/page.js

export default function MainThema({ params }) {
  const { themenID } = params;

  return <div>{themenID}</div>;
}
```

And if you need to get it in some nested client component, you should use the [`useParams`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-params) hook:

```js
// app/SomeClientComponent.js

'use client';

import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';

export default function SomeClientComponent() {
  const { themenID } = useParams();

  return <div>{themenID}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this should be more visible in the docs rather than just an API reference somewhere, IMO!

Comment: Is there a way for nested server components?