# I am using the new app Router in nextjs .getting Error:useRouter only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive to use it

Tags: next.js

```
./app/layout.tsx
ReactServerComponentsError:

You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead.

Import trace:
  ./app/layout.tsx
```

if i remove use useRouter and use useNavigation then i get the following

```
Error: (0 , next_navigation__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useNavigation) is not a function

Source
app/layout.tsx (18:30) @ useNavigation

  16 | children: React.ReactNode
  17 | }) {
> 18 | const router = useNavigation()
     |                            ^
  19 | 
  20 | const excludeHeader = router.pathname.startsWith('/admin')
```

if i add the use client on top of the file ,i get the following error

```
You are attempting to export "metadata" from a component marked with "use client", which is disallowed. Either remove the export, or the "use client" directive. Read more: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata

    ,-[/Users/veerpratap/Desktop/nodejs-projects/my-Next-apps/product-reviews/app/layout.tsx:5:1]
  5 | import MainHeader from './layout/main-header'
  6 | const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
  7 | 
  8 | export const metadata = {
    :              ^^^^^^^^
  9 |   title: 'Create Next App',
 10 |   description: 'Generated by create next app',
 11 | }
```

any way i can resolve this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component, but none of its parents are marked with "use client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965849/youre-importing-a-component-that-needs-usestate-it-only-works-in-a-client-comp)

Comment: do we have to define in every components if it is use client or use server

Comment: By default, they are server components. To make it a client component, either the component should have "use client", or its parent, the component that's calling it.

Comment: how can i use router basically in layout.tsx file?

Comment: import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import MainHeader from './layout/main-header'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

// export const metadata = {
//   title: 'Create Next App',
//   description: 'Generated by create next app',
// }

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const router = useRouter()

  const excludeHeader = router.pathname.startsWith('/admin')

  }

Comment: Add `"use client"` at the top and remove that `export const metadata = {`.

Comment: i want to use metadata for seo purpose

Comment: also even after using use state
and removing metadata

i am getting following error
User
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

Source
app/layout.tsx (19:26) @ useRouter

  17 | children: React.ReactNode
  18 | }) {
> 19 | const router = useRouter()
     |                        ^
  20 | 
  21 | const excludeHeader = router.pathname.startsWith('/admin')
  22 |

Comment: Whomever marked this as duplicate of useState does not understand the question. To use routing on the server see this thread instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76110930/read-url-dynamic-parameter-slug-with-next-js-in-the-app-folder

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me,

```
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
const pathname = usePathname();
```

[useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) from `next/navigation` doesn't export `pathname` etc anymore, as mentioned in the linked docs right before the [Router Events](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-events) section

Answer (score 2):

For server files (like APIs), if you want the named param of the path like `/users/[slug]/route.ts`, use `useParams()`, like

```
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'


export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const { slug } = useParams() as { slug: string }
  ...
```

Doesn't seem to be documented anywhere in nextJS. I got it from the source code. Thank God for typescript!

Comment: This is super annoying because they tell us to use useRouter to access the query parameters in their routing docs.

Answer (score 0):

In next latest version you can import from next/navigation:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
```

Answer (score 0):

`use client` needs to be placed at the very top.

Something like this:

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();
}
```