# Pass Dynamic route params to api route in Nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Hi there am struggling with how to send my client params to my GET request route the scenario i have is i have a Dynamic route with [id] and i have a list to access each book like this in client

```
<Link href={`/books/${id}}>Book {id}</Link>
```

And it open my page with book data so my api for that is a GET to get many books with that `id` so i need to pass this id to my server route in api folder.

Hi there am struggling with how to send my client params to my GET request route the scenario i have is i have a Dynamic route with [id] and i have a list to access each book like this in client

```
<Link href={`/books/${id}}>Book {id}</Link>
```

And it open my page with book data so my api for that is a GET to get many books with that `id` so i need to pass this id to my server route in api folde
r.

Comment: Hi Amr, welcome ! Please go through the linked thread's answer. And let us know if you think your problem is not solved (we will reopen it).

Comment: Thanks youssaf I saw the post and it really helped me but in my case i Don't get just one id i use my fetch like this fetch(/books) and get many readers with where id= the id i pass with params and am not sending it with fetch

Comment: If using a `Link`, the API route won't be called. Instead, the corresponding `page.js`, where you can get the id as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76113271/15288641

Comment: Yes i can get params with use params in client page then how to get it in api route in the server

Comment: As I just said, if you use a `Link` to navigate, and not `fetch`, the API route won't get called. Only the corresponding `page.js` will.

Comment: Am using the <Link> to navigate me to the <id> page.js to fetch data there