# How to use PrismaClient and usePathname together in the same component with Next.js 13's App Router

Tags: next.js, prisma

I'm trying to create a `Header` component that gets navigation links from a  database and shows which one is active currently.

I use Next.js `13` (app router) and Prisma as ORM. To get the current pathname I have to include `'use client'` otherwise, I cannot get the pathname because **"usePathname only works in Client Components."** But when I include `'use client'` I cannot use `PrismaClient` because I get an error that says **"PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser."** How can I use these two together?

Here's the code I used for **Header.tsx** component:

```jsx
'use client'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export async function getCategories() {
  const categories = await prisma.categories.findMany()
  return categories
}

export default async function Header(){
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const categories = await getCategories()
  return(
    <header>
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <Link href={"/"+category.slug} className={pathname == "/"+category.slug ? "menu-item item-active" : "menu-item"}>
           <span>{category.name}</span>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </header>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current pathname in the app directory of Next.js 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74584091/how-to-get-the-current-pathname-in-the-app-directory-of-next-js-13)

Comment: @YoussoufOumar No. I'm already able to get pathname with `use client`. But I can't use prisma with `use client`.

Comment: Checkout my below answer and let me know then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have both `use client` and `PrismaClient` in the same component. You could create a client `Nav` component and pass the `categories`  as prop:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import Nav from "./Nav"

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export async function getCategories() {
  const categories = await prisma.categories.findMany()
  return categories
}

export default async function Header(){
  const categories = await getCategories()
  return(
    <header>
     <Nav categories={categories} />
    </header>
  )
}
```

```
'use client'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'

export default async function Nav({categories}){
  const pathname = usePathname()
 
  return(
    <>
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <Link href={"/"+category.slug} className={pathname == "/"+category.slug ? "menu-item item-active" : "menu-item"}>
           <span>{category.name}</span>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```