# How to add conditional rendering based on URL in next.js rootlayout for app router v13.4?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, app-router

### What I am trying to achieve

I have a header that I need to change based on specific urls

---

### The issue

rootlayout doesn't allow me to conditionally render

```
import "./globals.css";
import localFont from "@next/font/local";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import HeaderDark from "./components/HeaderDark";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const darkHeaderUrls = ["talentica", "esign", "mickeytots"];

const trap = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/Trap-Light 300.otf",
      weight: "300",
    },
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/Trap-Regular 400.otf",
      weight: "400",
    },
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/Trap-Medium 500.otf",
      weight: "500",
    },
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/Trap-SemiBold 600.otf",
      weight: "600",
    },
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/Trap-Bold 700.otf",
      weight: "700",
    },
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/Trap-ExtraBold 800.otf",
      weight: "800",
    },
    {
      path: "../../public/fonts/Trap-Black 900.otf",
      weight: "900",
    },
  ],
  variable: "--font-trap",
});

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  // const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>The Design Trip</title>
        <meta name="description" content="One stop design solutions" />
      </head>
      <body className={`${trap.variable} font-sans`}>
        {/* {darkHeaderUrls.some((url) => pathname.includes(url)) ? (
          <HeaderDark />
        ) : ( */}
        <Header />
        {/* )} */}
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

---

The commented code is what I tried to do.
If I do this, next.js outputs an error saying that it can't be run on the server and i need to use the 'use client' flag, but on doing that I am not very sure this is the right way of doing it
What is the correct way to solve this problem?

---

### Concept

[next.js layout and template](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#templates)
According to this, I need to create a template if I wish to use hooks

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/76972597/15288641.